# How to scale images proportionally for higher resolutions?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Some of the images that I am using are small icons. How can I scale them when viewing them at much higher resolutions such as 2560 x 1440?

Comment: You can use this script http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/ . You just need to make 2 times bigger duplicate images and add them @2x at the end of their name. The script will then check if a duplicate image (with bigger dimension) exists and it will replace it :)

Answer (score 1):

Bojan is right: Using imulus.github.io/retinajs is a good way to accomplish this. A few things to note:

in your initial design, you should set your entire document to 150ppi. This is double resolution for retina display. When you're designing be sure all of the images and icons are scaleable to this size without pixelation.

Before you begin your build, cut out your images at this size and save them out like normal.Then scale it down to 72ppi so as you can cut out regular resolution images, and take measurements while you replicate the design into a website so you aren't constantly dividing by 2.

retinajs will replace your images as needed, but it will require you to assign dimensions to images that may not have them.

hope this helps